# How can I wrap STL container iterators that don't use contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, iterator, deque

I'm writing a custom container that internally uses a `std::deque` for its implementation. I want the container to support range-based `for` loops so implemented the `begin()` and `end()` functions. I don't want to expose the `std::deque::iterator` as the return value for `begin()` and `end()` so I wrote my own iterator in the custom container to return.

My iterator constructs via a pointer to the type that the custom container holds so I can dereference the `deque::begin()` iterator to construct.  But I can't deference `deque::end()` because it's undefined behaviour (although if I swap `deque` for `vector` it does work, but I imagine this is because of contiguous memory).

How do I properly wrap `std::deque` in this instance to be able to properly identify the `end()` of the container?

I could just implement this with a vector and implement the necessary `PushFront()` operation but I think it's an interesting question.

```cpp
struct Foo;

// Example custom container
class FooQueue{
public:

  FooId PushFront(Foo& foo);
  FooId PushBack(Foo& foo);
  void RemoveFoo(FooId id);

  // Custom iterator
  struct Iterator{
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = Foo;
    using pointer = value_type*;
    using reference = value_type&;

    explicit Iterator(pointer ptr) : ptr_(ptr){

    Iterator& operator++()
    {
      ptr_++;
      return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++(int)
    {
      Iterator tmp = *this;
      ptr_++;
      return tmp;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const Iterator& lhs, const Iterator& rhs){ return lhs.ptr_ == rhs.ptr_ };
    friend bool operator!=(const Iterator& lhs, const Iterator& rhs) { return !(lhs == rhs); }
  private:
    pointer ptr_;
  };

  Iterator begin(){ return Iterator(&(*deque_.begin())); }
  Iterator end() { return Iterator(&(*deque_.end())); } /* !!! Undefined behavior: Not allowed to
  dereference .end() !!! */
private:
  std::deque<Foo> deque_;
};
```

Comment: Why don't you let your iterator wrap the `std::deque::iterator`, just like your container wraps `std::deque`? Then the "pointer" of the iterator it the `std::deque::iterator`. Then all  your iterators functions and operators will be simple wrappers to the deque iterator functions and operators.

Comment: You could even `using iterator = std::deque::iterator; using const_iterator = std::deque::iterator;` in your class so that source code is unaffected by changes to the underlying container, but without having to implement the iterators yourself.

Comment: I just tried wrapping std::deque::iterator instead and it works perfectly. I was thinking too complex so thanks @Someprogrammerdude.

Comment: @TobySpeight Wouldn't aliasing the iterator still be exposing the type and therefore I'd have to export the std::deque::iterator (which I'm trying to avoid)?

Comment: @DWil It depends on what you mean by 'export'. If you change the type from `std::deque` to `std::vector` users of your class would have to recompile, but that but would be the case either way. The problem is, if you use `using Iterator = std::deque<Foo*>::iterator`, that the `value_type` of the iterator is `Foo*`. If you dereference an iterator, e.g. in a range based for loop (`for (auto& f: myFooQueue) { ... }`), `f` would be of type `Foo*` and not `Foo&`. If you want the iterator to dereference the pointer, you would have to write a wrapper iterator that does that.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't spotted that the deque is holding pointers, but the iterator is over values.  Thanks @chrysante for that observation!

Comment: @chrysante Sure, I get that. However, from my understanding the interface/symbols that a user would need to see from my library if I used the alias `using Iterator = std::deque<Foo>::iterator` would be that of std::deque. This wouldn't be a problem in Linux/macOS but it's painful in MSVC as exporting a class or interface that exposes an stl container isn't allowed and I'm trying to support all three platforms. By default I hide all symbols and explicitly declare what I export with a macro that effectively calls `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__attributr__((visibility("default"))`.

Comment: @chrysante that's actually a bug in my example. Apologies, I will edit it.

Comment: @DWil Yes, this 'exporting' behaviour of msvc with `__declspec(dllexport)` can be kind of annoying. I'm not 100% sure if a `using` declaration for the iterator will work there. Have you tried it? However one thing that you should to in this case, is to declare all special member functions (destructor, copy/move operations) and define them in the .cpp file (if possible as `=default`). Otherwise you might run into problems if you user code links a different version of the standard library (or even just another instance).

Comment: @chrysante Interestingly it does work. I'll run it through my CI and see if the other configurations catch anything.

Can I ask why I need to declare all special member functions? I don't define any of them (rule of one, three, five etc.) so aren't the implicit default ones not enough?